# Validating fields conditionally using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

I have the following validation rules for Laravel:

```
return [
    'offer_type' => 'required|in:permanent,temporary',
    'start_date' => 'required_if:offer_type,temporary|date_format:d/m/Y',
    'end_date' => 'required_if:offer_type,temporary|date_format:d/m/Y|after:start_date',
];
```

Basically, if the `offer_type` is `temporary`, a `start_date` and `end_date` is required and must follow the `d/m/Y` format. Also, the `end_date` must be after the `start_date`.

If the `offerType` is `permanent`, there is no need to validate `start_date` or `end_date` as they are not even used.

The issue I have is that it if the user sends data like the following:

- `offerType`: permanent
- `startDate`: foo
- `endDate`: bar

Then Laravel will raise a validation error, even though `start_date` and `end_date` does not need to be validated, as the offer type is `permanent`.

How can I make Laravel only validate `start_date` and `end_date` if `offer_type` is `temporary`.

**My (bad) Solution**

The only way I found around this issue was to do the following:

Change the above validation rules to the following:

```
return [
    'offer_type' => 'required|in:permanent,temporary',
    'start_date' => 'required_if:offer_type,temporary',
    'end_date' => 'required_if:offer_type,temporary',
];
```

and add the following code to the validator:

```
$validator->after(function (Validator $validator) {
    $data = $validator->getData();
    $failed = $validator->failed();

    if (array_key_exists('offerType', $data) &&
        $data['offerType'] === 'temporary' &&
        array_key_exists('start_date', $data) &&
        array_key_exists('end_date', $data) &&
        !array_key_exists('start_date', $failed) &&
        !array_key_exists('end_date', $failed)
    ) {
        $startDateString = $data['start_date'];
        $endDateString = $data['end_date'];

        $startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $startDateString);
        $endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $endDateString);

        if ($startDate === false) {
            $validator->errors()->add('start_date', 'Start date must be in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"');
        }

        if ($endDate === false) {
            $validator->errors()->add('end_date', 'End date must be in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"');
        }

        if ($startDate !== false && $endDate !== false && $endDate->lt($startDate)) {
            $validator->errors()->add('end_date', 'End date must be after or equal to the start date');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a separate FormRequest class. Then your `rules()` would look like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'offer_type' => 'required|in:permanent,temporary',
        'start_date' => 'required_if:offer_type,temporary',
        'end_date' => 'required_if:offer_type,temporary',
    ];

    if ($this->offer_type == 'permament') {
        $this->getInputSource()->remove('start_date'); // optionally you may remove start_date from request
        $this->getInputSource()->remove('end_date');  // same of end_date
        unset($rules['start_date']); 
        unset($rules['end_date']);
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Laravel Docs on [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation)